# Filtering Facebook GET act_id/customaudiences results

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I can't find a way to filter Custom audiences. From the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/custom-audience-api) it looks like is only possible to retrieve a list for a given actId and I can apply `fields` query param like this:

```
// Retrieve blank audience
curl \
-F "access_token=______" \
-F "fields=type,name,anyotherproperty" \
"https://graph.facebook.com/act_XXXXXXX/customaudiences"
```

What I need is a way to retrieve only the custom audiences with `subtype='CUSTOM'` and with `creation_source.type='file'`

Can anybody help me with this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no server-side filtering available on the `/<AD_ACCOUNT>/customaudiences` endpoint - you'll need to cache and filter the response in your own app's code

Comment: Thank you very much. You just confirmed my impression.
Bye!

Comment: Would be nice to state such facts in the documentation.

Comment: I don't think negatives or non existent functionality is usually documented - if there was such a filtering option, I'm sure it would be documented - much of the Facebook API documentation is auto generated these days